# Каким образом можно остановить дрожание

Tags: javascript, canvas

Я написал нечто вроде сетки, но скрипт работает только наполовину.
*Если нажать куда-либо, а затем отпустить, сетка совершит попытку восстановиться*, как и до нажатия, но попытка окажется неудачной и **все квадраты продолжат дрожать**.

**Мой вопрос: как прекратить дрожание?**
Я совершенно без понятия, как это сделать.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>.</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0">
 <canvas id="can" style="display: block"></canvas>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function getId(o) {return document.getElementById(o)};
  let can = getId('can'), ctx = can.getContext('2d'), rnd = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * ((max + 1) - min) + min),
  walls = [], mouse = {
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   down: false
  },
  Wall = class {
   constructor(x, y, width, height, color, speed, nativePosition) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y,
    this.width = width,
    this.height = height,
    this.color = color,
    this.speed = speed,
    this.nativePosition = nativePosition,

    this.velocity = {
     x: 0,
     y: 0,
     friction: .9
    }
   }
  }, size = {
   width: 25,
   height: 25
  };

  for(let x = 0; x < innerWidth / size.width; x++) {
   for(let y = 0; y < innerHeight / size.height; y++) {
    walls.push( new Wall(x * size.width, y * size.height, size.width, size.height, "#555", rnd(2, 4), {x: x * size.width, y: y * size.height}) )
   }
  };

  onresize = e => {
   can.width = innerWidth;
   can.height = innerHeight
  };
  onresize();
  can.style.background = "#000";

  document.onmousemove = e => {
   mouse.x = e.clientX;
   mouse.y = e.clientY
  };
  document.onmousedown = () => mouse.down = true;
  document.onmouseup = () => mouse.down = false;

  (loop = () => {
   ctx.fillStyle = "#0003";
   ctx.fillRect(-3e38, -3e38, 3e38 * 2, 3e38 * 2);

   walls.forEach(wall => {
    if(mouse.down) {
     let a = mouse.x - wall.x - wall.width / 2,
     b = mouse.y - wall.y - wall.height / 2,

     len = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b), speed = wall.speed;

     a = a / (len ? len : 1) * speed;
     b = b / (len ? len : 1) * speed;

     wall.velocity.x *= wall.velocity.friction;
     wall.velocity.y *= wall.velocity.friction;

     wall.velocity.x += a;
     wall.velocity.y += b;

     wall.x += wall.velocity.x;
     wall.y += wall.velocity.y
    } else {
     let a = wall.nativePosition.x - wall.x,
     b = wall.nativePosition.y - wall.y,

     len = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b), speed = wall.speed;

     a = a / (len ? len : 1) * speed;
     b = b / (len ? len : 1) * speed;

     wall.velocity.x *= wall.velocity.friction;
     wall.velocity.y *= wall.velocity.friction;

     wall.velocity.x += a;
     wall.velocity.y += b;

     wall.x += wall.velocity.x;
     wall.y += wall.velocity.y
    };

    ctx.strokeStyle = wall.color;
    ctx.strokeRect(wall.x, wall.y, wall.width, wall.height)
   });

   requestAnimationFrame(loop)
  })();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Там где-то надо прописать дельту. Если координата примерно в этой дельте, то стопорить.Именно стопорить, а не делать `wall.x +=` и `wall.y +=`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Как Вам такой вариант?

Мне кажется в Вашем случае не стоит увеличивать скорость при отлете от точки назначения, когда квадраты возвращаются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let ctx = can.getContext('2d'),
  rnd = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * ((max + 1) - min) + min),
  walls = [],
  mouse = {x: 0, y: 0, down: false },
  Wall = function(x, y, width, height, color, speed) {
      this.x = x,
      this.y = y,
      this.width = width,
      this.height = height,
      this.color = color,
      this.speed = speed,
      this.nativePosition = {x,y},
      this.velocity = {x: 0, y: 0, friction: .91}
  },
  size = {width: 26,height: 26};

for (let x = 0; x < innerWidth / size.width; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < innerHeight / size.height; y++) {
    walls.push(new Wall(x * size.width, y * size.height, size.width, size.height, "#999", rnd(2, 4)))
  }
};

(onresize = e => {
  can.width = innerWidth;
  can.height = innerHeight;
})();

document.onmousemove = e => {
  mouse.x = e.clientX;
  mouse.y = e.clientY;
};

document.onmousedown = e => mouse.down = true;
document.onmouseup = e => mouse.down = false;

(loop = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0008";
  ctx.fillRect(-3e38, -3e38, 3e38 * 2, 3e38 * 2);

  walls.forEach(wall => {
    let a, b, d = mouse.down;
    if (d) {
      a = mouse.x - wall.x - wall.width / 2;
      b = mouse.y - wall.y - wall.height / 2;
      len = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b) || 1;
      a = a / len * wall.speed;
      b = b / len * wall.speed;
    } else {
      a = wall.nativePosition.x - wall.x;
      b = wall.nativePosition.y - wall.y;
    }

    wall.velocity.x *= wall.velocity.friction;
    wall.velocity.y *= wall.velocity.friction;
    wall.velocity.x += a * Math.random() / (d ? 1 : 5);
    wall.velocity.y += b * Math.random() / (d ? 1 : 5);
    wall.x += wall.velocity.x;
    wall.y += wall.velocity.y

    ctx.strokeStyle = wall.color;
    ctx.strokeRect(wall.x+3, wall.y+3, wall.width-3, wall.height-3)
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
})();
```

```css
body, #can {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
```

Comment: Просто Супер...